# Filtering through the association -- missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model2
  # fields f1
end


class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :model1
  # fields f2
end
```

How can I filter all Model1 by f1 == ? and Model2 by f2 == ? through their association? I've tried this:

```
Model1.where(f1: my_f1).where('model2.f2 > ?', my_f2)
```

but got an error:

```
 PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "model2"
```

Comment: you should use joins, to query over two relational models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model1.joins(:model2).where('model1.f1 = ? AND model2.f2 = ?', my_f1, my_f2)
```